# force jquery mouseover not to trigger when over children, just parent

Tags: jquery

I have an `<a>` with a `<img>` inside, and I want something to happen when hovering over the `<a>` which works, the problem is that if I move the cursor over the image inside, it triggers again.

Is there a way to force it to trigger when over `<a>` only, and not the child (which is smaller than the parent).

my js:

```
$('#logo a').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('div#header-contact').fadeIn();
    });
```

Comment: You might find more information on QuirksMode if you are interested in why: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is [mouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/mouseover) event bubbles to the ancestor elements, so you can use the [mouseenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mouseenter) event which doesn't bubbles

Try the mouseenter event

```
$('#logo a').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('div#header-contact').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: it never occurred to me my even was wrong, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop propagation/bubbling of events to the children

[event.stoppropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```
$('#logo a').mouseover(function(event) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('div#header-contact').fadeIn();
        event.stopPropagation()
    });
```

or you can use the mouse enter event

```
$('#logo a').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('div#header-contact').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#logo a').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('div#header-contact').fadeIn();
});


$('#logo a img').mouseover(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

stop the mouseover event on child:

```
$('#logo a').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('div#header-contact').fadeIn();
    }).children().mouseover(function() {
  return false;
});
```