# Prevent mouseenter event parent

Tags: jquery, css

From what I have read in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328413/force-jquery-mouseover-not-to-trigger-when-over-children-just-parent), I would expect that when I enter a div by hitting a child element first, the mouseenter event of the parent does not fire. However, it does.

Here is an [example](http://www.esims.nl/test/aspnet/2017_08_stackoverflow/) to make it clear. I want the mouseenter event only to fire when I hit the blue area, not when I hit the child element. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of the event bubbling. If a child element doesn't handle an event, their parent will have the chance to do it.

If you want to prevent this from happening, you will need to handle the event at "child-level". If you return `false` in your event handler, the event will stop traversing the DOM, and the parent's event handler won't run.

[Example on CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PKBKqo)

Comment: The question I referred to had an accepted answer which said that the mouseenter event does not bubble. I guess this is not correct?

Comment: To be precise, it indeed does not bubble, but each element in the tree gets ["its own" event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter). Regardless, the `stopPropagation` call (caused by `return false` in the jQuery handler) seems to prevent subsequent events from firing. [This is also a good summary on the subject](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/different-between-mouseover-and-mouseenter-in-jquery/)